How can I split a string on whitespaces or quotes if they're present
Context: I have a list of keywords that sometimes consist of one word (e.g. poisson, normal, ...) and sometimes consist of two words, which are then within single quotes ('Two-way ANOVA', 'Generalized linear model', ...). All keywords are separated by white spaces in a single string.
Question: How can extract each keyword of the list, accounting for the ones that are within single quotes ?
Example:
What I have:
kw <- "poisson normal 'negative binomial' log-likelihood"

What I want:
c("poisson", "normal", "negative binomial", "log-likelihood")


by using either:
stringr::str_split(kw, pattern = " ") or
stringr::str_split(kw, pattern = "'")

But that won't work. It will either split negative and binomial into separate keywords, or it won't split poisson and normal into separate keywords

We could use a regex find all trick here and match on the following pattern:
'.*?'|\S+

This will eagerly try to find a singly-quoted term, and that failing will fallback to matching any other non quoted term.
library(stringr)

kw <- "poisson normal 'negative binomial' log-likelihood"
output <- str_extract_all(kw, "'.*?'|\\S+")
output

[[1]]
[1] "poisson"             "normal"              "'negative binomial'"
[4] "log-likelihood"  


This exactly what I needed, thanks a lot ! Could you please explain the logic behind the regex pattern ?

@A.Bohyn I did explain in my answer, but to add, the '.*?' term will be attempted first.  This means that there is never any chance of consuming a non whitespace word inside single quotes.  If the pattern can't match a quoted term, then it will match any non space word term.

You could use this regex pattern with lookbehind (?<=') and lookahead (?=') to match terms inside quotation marks if you don't want to return the quotation marks themselves. After that find all words, optionally with a - character in them.
stringr::str_extract_all(kw, pattern = "(?<=').+(?=')|[\\w-]+") 

[[1]]
[1] "poisson"           "normal"            "negative binomial"
[4] "log-likelihood"   

